# ListView not showing data from custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

My `getView()` method for customized `ListViewAdapter` is as follows :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
ArrayList mArray;
ArrayList<Item> mArray2;
DBHelper mydb;
String dbName;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = inflater;
    mArray = new ArrayList();
    mArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
    mydb = new DBHelper(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mArray.get(position);
}

public Item getItem2(int position) { return mArray2.get(position); }


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // your particular data set uses String IDs
    // but you have to put something in this method
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    // check if the view already exists
    // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
    if (convertView == null) {

        // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // create a new "Holder" with subviews
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.itemExpiryView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_expiry);

        // Taking care of the buttons
        holder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

        // hang onto this holder for future recycling
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        // skip all the expensive inflation/findViewById
        // and just get the holder you already made
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set listener on the buttons
    holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Edit Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = getItem(position).toString();

            int id = mydb.getID(dbName, name);
            mydb.deleteItem(dbName, id);
            mArray2 = mydb.getAllItemsAsCollection(dbName);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Doing for 2nd case
    Item _item = getItem2(position);
    String name2 = _item.name;
    System.out.println(name2);
    String ex = _item.expiry;
    System.out.println(ex);

    // For the second case
    holder.itemNameView.setText(name2);
    holder.itemExpiryView.setText(ex);


    return convertView;
}

// this is used so you only ever have to do
// inflation and finding by ID once ever per View
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView itemNameView;
    public TextView itemExpiryView;
    public Button editButton;
    public Button deleteButton;
}

public void updateData2(ArrayList<Item> arrayPassed) {
    // update the adapter's data set
    mArray2 = arrayPassed;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setDbName(String dbName){
    this.dbName = dbName;
}


}
```

The `DBHelper` class function `getAllItemsAsCollection()` is defined as below :

```
public ArrayList<Item> getAllItemsAsCollection(String dbName)
{
    ArrayList<Item> array_list = new ArrayList<Item>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + dbName, null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        String n = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
        String e = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPIRY));
        String c = dbName;

        Item _item = new Item(n, e, c);
        array_list.add(_item);

        res.moveToNext();
    }

    return array_list;
}
```

And also, the `insertItem()` function inside `DBHelper` is this :

```
public boolean insertItem  (String dbName, String name, String expiry)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("expiry", expiry);
    db.insert(dbName, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

I have added a separate class for customizable object handing :

```
public class Item {

String name;
String expiry;
String category;

Item(String n, String e, String c){
    this.name = n;
    this.expiry = e;
    this.category = c;
}

}
```

And the `addItem()` method inside `MainActivity.java` works like :

```
public void addItem(final View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    LinearLayout lila1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    lila1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    final EditText name = new EditText(this);
    name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
    final EditText days = new EditText(this);
    days.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
    TextView text_ex = new TextView(this);
    text_ex.setText("In how many days will it expire..");

    alert.setTitle("Hello!");
    alert.setMessage("What did you buy today..");
    lila1.addView(name);
    lila1.addView(text_ex);
    lila1.addView(days);
    alert.setView(lila1);


    // Make an "OK" button to save the name
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            // Grab the EditText's input
            String inputName = name.getText().toString();
            String daysToExpiry = days.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(daysToExpiry);
            mydb.insertItem(currentDB, inputName, daysToExpiry);
            System.out.println("Worked");

            // For 2nd Case
            currentList2 = mydb.getAllItemsAsCollection(currentDB);

            System.out.println("Random Musings");
            itemAdder2.updateData2(currentList2);

            // addItemToList(inputName, v);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Make a "Cancel" button
    // that simply dismisses the alert
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

I have initiaized every variable correctly. When I try to run my app, and try to add a new item, the `Dialog box` just vanishes and there is nothing shown in the layout. I tried with a simple `ArrayList<Strings>` before and it worked perfectly. That is why I believe there should not be any problem with the `.xml Layout`. And might be with the `ListViewAdapter.updateData2()` function. Please Help. Appreciate your patience going through these long pieces of code. If any further info is required, please let me know. Thanks a lot. :)

Forgot to attach the `.xml` for actual view. This worked perfectly with `ArrayList<String>`. I have already tested. When I tried to pass complex object, in this case, `Item-class object`, and correspondingly an `ArrayList<Item>`, my guess is, I could not write the adapter portion code correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:clickable="true" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where you add data to adapter and set adapter to listview? Can you print that piece of code?

Comment: What do you want to show in each row? just two textviews or two textviews plus two buttons? If so you better extend ArrayAdapter which is easier directly extending BaseAdapter.

Comment: @Beyka The `addItem()` function is used to add the data to my database. Inside that function, I call `updateData2()` to set the adapter with an `ArrayList<Item>`. The `getView()` function inside `ListViewAdapter` sets the view. My `itemAdder2` is a `ListViewAdapter` class object. 

@Erfan I wil definitey try that out. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Beyka I have already posted the corresponding code you asked for. So, not sharing the code snippet.